# Local issuer certificate error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-socialite

I am using **socialite** and using google for OAuth. When I authorize the application which results in the following error.

[image]

I also used facebook where I get the same error. But I fixed it by creating **cacert.pem** and placing its path in `php.ini`. Then why I am getting this error with google. It should work with google as well but it is not.

**OS: windows with XAMPP**

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows.

Comment: might this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/717181 problem is your php curl command does not have access to (valid) intermediate ca certificate files.

Answer (score 1):

**The reason** you're seeing this is with socialite is that, underlying socialite use `guzzlehttp`, if you look at `composer.json` for socialite package.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "illuminate/contracts": "~5.0",
    "illuminate/http": "~5.0",
    "illuminate/support": "~5.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0|~6.0",
    "league/oauth1-client": "~1.0"
},
```

and `guzzlehttp` use curl for all kind of requests, now all the providers like facebook, google, twitter use `O-Auth` over `https` protocol.

**To Solve**

First of all download the ssl-certificates from    https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and save these. `(click on cacert.pem)`

Next goto `[You XAMPP Installation]\php\php.ini` and locate `;curl.cainfo=`, un-comment this and give path of your downloaded    certificate file like this.`curl.cainfo=[Path to    cacert.pem]\cacert.pem`

Restart XAMPP and you're good to go.